# Render an animated fbx model with texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx, 3d-model

I am working to display "animated 3D Models" on webpage. These models are in form of .obj, .mtl & .fbx files with texture and without texture. I successfully displayed .obj 3D Models on webpage (with texture , with mtl file), **but i am unable to display .fbx 3D animated models with texture.**

I already searched for this topic on Google, SO and also on Github (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues) but not found any solution.

I want to ask 2 questions here:

1. Is it possible to display fbx 3D Models with texture via three.js?
2. If it is possible then how i can do this **OR** if it is not then what other alternative can i use to render fbx model having texture to webpage?

Comment: One way I know is importing your model to blender (from .fbx) and then [exporting it to three json](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender) format.

Comment: Hi @mlkn, 
thanks for your reply, i am js developer not a 3D designer. 3D designers gave me .fbx files with texture to render. After lots of R & D, i found three.js as a solution. But FBXLoader Library of three.js not supports texture. Since it would be dynamically, user will upload their model file and i have to render directly on webpage. So i can not use any converter manually.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of time i have understood that you can not use .fbx model file directly with three.js (till r82). Alternatively you can convert .fbx file to .json (using three.js maya exporter )or .js (using blender).
So i am moving with .json file format. Thanks for your suggestion @mlkn